# memcmp VS wmemcmp - сравнение скорости

Tags: c++, c

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему wmemcmp работает раза в 2-5 медленнее memcmp.
Вот код для сравнения:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
wchar_t my_wchar11[] = L"rstuw12345612345ab89abcefghijklmnopqrstuw123457q"; 
wchar_t my_wchar22[] = L"rstuw12345612345ab89abcefghijklmnopqrstuw123457q"; 

        //----------------------------------------------
        wchar_t* my_wchar_p11 = new wchar_t[wcslen(my_wchar11)+1];
        wchar_t* my_wchar_p22 = new wchar_t[wcslen(my_wchar22)+1];

        memcpy(my_wchar_p11, my_wchar11, sizeof(my_wchar11));
        memcpy(my_wchar_p22, my_wchar22, sizeof(my_wchar22));
        //----------------------------------------------
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        size_t num = 99999999;
        int clock1;
        int clock2;


//------------------------------------------------------Сравнение через wmemcmp:-----------------------

        clock1 = clock();
        int status_wmemcmp = 0;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < num; i++)
        {
            status_wmemcmp = wmemcmp(my_wchar_p11, my_wchar_p22, wcslen(my_wchar22));
        }
        clock2 = clock();

        cout << "time_wmemcmp:" << clock2 - clock1 << endl;
        cout << "status_wmemcmp:" << status_wmemcmp << endl;

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        cout << endl;

//------------------------------------------------------Сравнение через memcmp:----------------------

        clock1 = clock();
        int status_memcmp = 0;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < num; i++)
        {
            status_memcmp = memcmp(my_wchar_p11, my_wchar_p22, sizeof(my_wchar22)-2);
        }
        clock2 = clock();

        cout << "time_memcmp:" << clock2 - clock1 << endl;
        cout << "status_memcmp:" << status_memcmp << endl;
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

}
```

Результаты следующие: VS2017, release, x64:

wmemcmp: 2352 мс

memcmp:  853  мс

Причем на бОльших массивов разница еще больше.

Comment: ¿А вас не смущает, что при каждом вызове `wmemcmp` еще вызывается `wcslen`?

Comment: user7860670, не очень, так как при каждом вызове memcmp есть sizeof и такая разница не может быть вызвана wcslen`ом и замена вызова wcslen на фиксированное число это подтвердило. Результат прежний 2352 против 853 мс.

Comment: хм. вот sizeof - это константа времени компиляции а не функция. Однако более подробное изучение показывает, что для memcmp просто используется быстрый ассемблерный вариант, а для wmemcmp его нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это особенность реализации в MSVCRT. `memcmp` в MSVCRT написана на ассемблере. Исходник у меня в системе лежит в файле `c:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/crt/src/x64/memcmp.asm`. Чистый ассемблер без единой Си-шной строчки.

`wmemcmp` в MSVCRT написана на Си. Реализация включена в заголовочный файл `c:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.17763.0/ucrt/wchar.h`
Реализовано без затей простым циклом:

```
    __inline int __CRTDECL wmemcmp(
        _In_reads_(_N) wchar_t const* _S1,
        _In_reads_(_N) wchar_t const* _S2,
        _In_           size_t         _N
        )
    {
        for (; 0 < _N; ++_S1, ++_S2, --_N)
            if (*_S1 != *_S2)
                return *_S1 < *_S2 ? -1 : 1;

        return 0;
    }
```

Для сравнения, в GLIBC несколько ассемблерных реализаций [w]memcmp, оптимизированных под разные расширения процессора, [см. репозиторий glibc](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=tree;f=sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch;hb=HEAD). Есть и чисто Си-шная реализация, в которой цикл развёрнут. Разворачивание цикла дало прирост в полтора раза по сравнению с простым циклом. Для сравнения я взял [Си версию wmemcmp из исходников glibc](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob_plain;f=wcsmbs/wmemcmp.c;h=2dcdd7195747ed96fea4d3a070bb01c1fc51da26;hb=HEAD)

Получился [вот такой main.cpp](https://pastebin.com/vBmrdzrL)

Компиляция в MS VC 19.16.27044: `cl.exe /O2 main.cpp`

32-х битный компилятор:

```
time_wmemcmp:2389
status_wmemcmp:0

time_memcmp:674
status_memcmp:0

time_glibc_wmemcmp:1614
status_glibc_wmemcmp:0
```

64-х битный компилятор

```
time_wmemcmp:2210
status_wmemcmp:0

time_memcmp:1263
status_memcmp:0

time_glibc_wmemcmp:1789
status_glibc_wmemcmp:0
```

g++ 7.5.0 64-х битный, на той же самой машине, запускался под WSL: `g++ -O2 main.cpp -o g_main.exe`

```
time_wmemcmp:1062500
status_wmemcmp:0

time_memcmp:1000000
status_memcmp:0

time_glibc_wmemcmp:1703125
status_glibc_wmemcmp:0
```

Интересно, что в 64-х битном компиляторе `memcmp` в два раза медленнее, чем 32-х битная версия.

Answer (score 1):

переписал код так, чтобы более-менее обмануть компилятор и он не начал почём зря оптимизировать (у меня например `memcmp` работает вообще 0ms в Release)

результаты:

x64:

```
time_wmemcmp:2101
status_wmemcmp:0

time_memcmp:913
status_memcmp:0
```

x86:

```
time_wmemcmp:2189
status_wmemcmp:0

time_memcmp:952
status_memcmp:0
```

что и должно быть, поскольку для wchar_t требуется обработать в 2 раза больше информации

мой вердикт - в приведённом автором поста коде компилятор для memcmp просто более хорошо соптимизировал код

код:

```
    const wchar_t my_wchar11[] = L"rstuw12345612345ab89abcefghijklmnopqrstuw123457q";
    const wchar_t my_wchar22[] = L"rstuw12345612345ab89abcefghijklmnopqrstuw123457q";

    const char my_char11[] = "rstuw12345612345ab89abcefghijklmnopqrstuw123457q";
    const char my_char22[] = "rstuw12345612345ab89abcefghijklmnopqrstuw123457q";

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    const size_t num = 99999999;
    int clock1;
    int clock2;

    //------------------------------------------------------Сравнение через wmemcmp:-----------------------

    clock1 = clock();
    int status_wmemcmp = 0;
    const int wlen = wcslen(my_wchar22);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        const int pos = i % wlen;
        status_wmemcmp += wmemcmp(my_wchar11 + pos, my_wchar22 + pos, wlen - pos);
    }
    clock2 = clock();

    cout << "time_wmemcmp:" << clock2 - clock1 << endl;
    cout << "status_wmemcmp:" << status_wmemcmp << endl;

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    cout << endl;

    //------------------------------------------------------Сравнение через memcmp:----------------------

    clock1 = clock();
    const int len = strlen(my_char22);
    int status_memcmp = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        const int pos = i % len;
        status_memcmp += memcmp(my_char11 + pos, my_char22 + pos, len - pos);
    }
    clock2 = clock();

    cout << "time_memcmp:" << clock2 - clock1 << endl;
    cout << "status_memcmp:" << status_memcmp << endl;
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Zhihar, у меня ваш код выдает на x64: wmwmcmp:2179 против memcmp: 1193. Ну видимо возможно, как и написал user7860670 - "для memcmp просто используется быстрый ассемблерный вариант", хотя не понятно почему microsoft не смог сделать аналогично с memcmp.

Comment: @Optimus1, мой код для `wmemcmp` передаётся в 2 раза больше байт, поэтому он должен работать в 2 раза дольше, но в вашем случае он работает побыстрее, что можно объяснить, что в wmemcmp в среднем получается меньше вспомогательных расчетов на 1 байт

если хотите измерить 1 в 1 скорость 2 функций - тогда my_char11 и mychar22 просто увеличьте в 2 раза (продублируйте символы в строке)

как я понимаю это 2 функции, которые работают одинаково и с одинаковой скоростью - можно было бы посмотреть в дизассемблере - возможно wmemcmp вызывает просто memcmp

Comment: Zhihar, но это же не очень корректно, memcmp - принимает на вход void* - и поэтому правильнее сравнивать именно один и тот же массив wchar_t, а не удвоенный char.

Comment: @Optimus1, переделал код- все равно отрыв в 2 раза сохранился, странно, возможно дело с тем, что поскольку функции выдают некоторое значение, а не просто равно/не равно, то для обсчёта двойных байт требуется какая-то дополнительная логика, которая и затормаживает работу функции?

Comment: ответ не верен... *user7860670* в комментариях к вопросу уже правильно сказал — не считая огрехов методики тестирования, для `wmemcmp` используется наивная реализация (которая встраивается), а для `memcpy` — библиотечная и оптимизированная... это проблема исключительно реализации msvc/msvcrt... ничего интересного тут нет... разница в 2 раза — просто случайность... для строк разного размера она может плавать...